# count class instances for every derived class

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop, inheritance

is there any way to make all derived classes count their instances?How (write code in one of C++, C#, Java)?

Imagine I've got access to the root class (e.g. object), and every other class is (directly or indirectly) derived from this class. What I want is:

```
AnyDerivedClass.InstancesCount()
```

Problem is, one must keep track of count in static variable, but it is not possible to "inject" static variable into derived class from base class, this holds only for member variables.
That is, I have to write something like:

```
class object 
{ 
 private static int count = 0; 
 protected object() { ++count; }
 protected ~object() { --count; } 
 public static InstancesCount() { return count; } 
};

class derived : object 
{
 private static int count = 0;
 public derived() { ++count; }
 public ~derived() { --count; }
 public static InstancesCount() { return count; }
}
```

This functionality is obviously repeated, and I cannot put it in base class.
Note there are 2 ways of calculating: that if there are 7 instances of class derived1 and 8 instances of class derived2, there are (a) 15 instances of object or (b) 0 instances of object. I don't care which one, because I can't do neither (using reasonably practical means, e.g. imagine 100 classes, half of which are in library I cannot modify).

Of course, in theory it is possible to create map of (some run-type type identifier) => int count, and use ugly, slow, (run-time type)-based approach (at least in C#, Java).

Of course, if I can modify derived classes, I can use copy-paste (awful), macro (yeah I know), mixins (not in these languages) etc. But that is still real ugly.

This is specific problem, but It happened to me several times, that I'd like to be able to "inject" static member into derived class to solve problem elegantly.

Help much appreciated.

EDIT: thanks for good answer, in C++ it is possibly to use CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern) as well, but not in C#/Java (no multiple inheritance). Of course, one must have access to derived classes and add this base class, so question remains (in case there is no other way, this looks best).

EDIT 2: looks impossible with current languages. static part of every class is not inheriting (and that's right), but there is no inheriting singleton associated with every class, so these kinds of problems cannot be solved so elegantly. 
To illustrate things, look at the following code: normal members and static members are current OOP languages feature, "singleton" (or whatever word would be) members are my suggestion/desire:

```
class Base
{
    static int sMemberBase;
    int memberBase;

    //my wish (note that virtual for methods is allowed!):
    singleton int singletonMemberBase;
};
class Derived : Base
{
    static int sMemberDerived;
    int memberDerived;

    //my wish (note that virtual for methods is allowed!):
    singleton int singletonMemberDerived;
};

//taken apart: (note: XYZStatic classes do not derive)
class Base { int memberBase; }
class BaseStatic { int sMemberBase; } BaseStaticInstance;
class Derived : Base { int memberDerived; }
class DerivedStatic { int sMemberDerived;  } BaseStaticInstance;
//note: Derived::sMemberBase is compile-time changed to Base::sMemberBase

//my wish: (note inheritance!)
class BaseSingleton { int singletonMemberBase; } BaseSingletonInstance;
class DerivedSingleton : BaseSingleton { int singletonMemberDerived; } DerivedSingletonInstance;
```

If anything like that would be present in language, solution for my question would be simple and elegant:

```
//with singleton members, I could write counter like this:
class object
{
    singleton int count;
    object() { ++count; }
    ~object() { --count; }
};
```

Comment: What are you doing? -- How many instances you are counting that you think about performance issues of "run-time type-based approach"?

Comment: +1 for an interesting q.

Comment: there is huge performance difference between "run-type type-based" approach in comparison for simple increment/decrement, for big project that could mean slowdown; however, it's more generic question about injecting static functionality into derived classes as well ;-)

Answer (score 10):

In C++, you can do it with a template base class. Basically it *is* a mixin, so it does still require each class to co-operate by inheriting from the mixin:

```
// warning: not thread-safe
template <typename T>
class instance_counter {
  public:
    static size_t InstancesCount() { return count(); }
    instance_counter() { count() += 1; }
    instance_counter(const instance_counter&) { count() += 1; }
    // rare case where we don't need to implement the copy assignment operator.
  protected:
    ~instance_counter() { count() -= 1; }
  private:
    static size_t &count {
        static size_t counter = 0;
        return counter;
    }
};

class my_class: public instance_counter<my_class> {};
```

Since each class using the template has a *different* base class, it has a *different* `count` function and hence a different copy of the static variable `counter`.

The trick of inheriting from a template class that's instantiated using the derived class as a template parameter is called CRTP.

Comment: no, it is NOT a mixin, mixin does not add base class! that's why we don't have mixins in c++ and have mixins in languages that does not support multiple inheritance?

Comment: +1 didn't realize this possibility (looks like best one for c++), but question remains

Comment: @Serge: What are you talking about? The instance_counter doesn't replace the poor design that is Object. You just inherit from it if you want your instances counted- that's it.

Comment: @peenut: "interfaces" do not add base classes either, at least not in Java. But in C++ interfaces are implemented using base classes. Anyway, it doesn't really matter what you call it, C++ has a mechanism for a static version of something that mixins and monkey-patches can do in other languages, sometimes dynamically. That is, they add member functions to a class, and those functions can use properties of the class they're added to. That mechanism is CRTP (base classes again, with a twist). In this simple case, the only property of the class we're using is its identity.

Comment: If you didn't want to use inheritance, are there any down sides (aside from increasing the size[unaligned] of the class by 1) having an instance of the `instance_counter` in the class that wants to be counted?

Comment: @peenut: btw, Wikipedia defines that mixins *always* use inheritance. I'm not saying that's the One True Definition of a mixin, but I do think the term is used more generally than you're allowing.

Comment: @Nim: Don't think so, in this case we're really not mixing *much* in, so a data member would do the job without having to mess about forwarding any calls to it. As you imply, the benefit of inheritance is that it gives EBO a chance to kick in. Might be an idea to use private inheritance, actually, although that hides the fact that the class is counted from users of the class - with it public, people can do compile-time checks if they want.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Wikipedia is not bible :-), obvious difference is, what you wrote adds base class, mixins in languages that natively support them, do not add base class, difference is e.g. in type casting, it does not matter in this case, but there IS a difference

Comment: @peenut: it's not the One True Definition, but it does reflect real usage of the word. For another example, Symbian described base classes with no data members as "mixins" (or "M-classes") for years. This isn't a meaning I've just made up :-) I'm quite happy to accept that in other languages "mixin" means something different and/or more specific, with the same general purpose.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: let's agree that definition varies with language, so I suggest peace :-D

Comment: @DeadMG: but what if one needs to have a container with the objects of classes that are capable of self-counting?

Comment: @Serge: The class only offers reference counting. It doesn't even have any virtual functions. What on earth would be the use? You inherit from this class *in addition to* Object, and then you store a container of Objects.

Comment: @Steve quick question, what's the reason for making the ~dtor protected but the ctor's public? It doesn't seem like `instance_counter` is meant to be instantiated and used directly why not make the default and copy ctor protected too?

Comment: @Victor T: The protected destructor stops someone doing something dangerous (deleting through the wrong type). A protected constructor stops someone doing something pointless and stupid (creating an instance of the class that does nothing for them, and that they can't destroy). Sounds like a good idea to make the ctors protected too. It just fell below my threshold of worrying about it, whereas I always worry about destructors.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use a global `Multiset`:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ConcurrentHashMultiset;

public abstract class InstanceCounted {

    protected InstanceCounted() {
        COUNT_MAP.add(this.getClass());
    }

    protected static final ConcurrentHashMultiset<Class<? extends InstanceCounted>> COUNT_MAP =
        ConcurrentHashMultiset.create();

}
```

Alternatively you can use a `Map<Class, Integer>` if you don't want the dependency on guava.

Note: this only tracks instance *creation*, not garbage collection, so the count will never decrease.  You can also track collection using `PhantomReference`s if you are willing to take a performance hit:

```
import java.lang.ref.PhantomReference;
import java.lang.ref.Reference;
import java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue;

import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimaps;

public abstract class InstanceCounted {

    public static int getInstanceCount(Class<? extends InstanceCounted> clazz) {
        reap();
        return INSTANCES.get(clazz).size();
    }

    protected InstanceCounted() {
        reap();
        INSTANCES.put(getClass(), new CountingReference(this));
    }

    static final Multimap<Class<? extends InstanceCounted>, CountingReference> INSTANCES =
        Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap(HashMultimap.<Class<? extends InstanceCounted>, CountingReference>create());

    static final ReferenceQueue<InstanceCounted> QUEUE =
        new ReferenceQueue<InstanceCounted>();

    private static void reap() {
        Reference<? extends InstanceCounted> ref;
        while ((ref = QUEUE.poll()) != null) {
            ((CountingReference) ref).clear();
        }
    }

    private static class CountingReference extends PhantomReference<InstanceCounted> {

        public void clear() {
            super.clear();
            INSTANCES.remove(clazz, this);
        }

        CountingReference(InstanceCounted instance) {
            super(instance, QUEUE);
            this.clazz = instance.getClass();
        }

        private final Class<? extends InstanceCounted> clazz;

    }

}
```

Comment: yes, (run-time type)-based solution possible, however much slower. to count instance garbage, use Java's finalizer ;-)

Comment: @peenut, I do not recommend overriding `finalize`, but I added an example that achieves the same thing using `PhantomReference`.

Comment: ok, ok, there are weak, soft, phantom etc. it was more for illustration of concept, but you're right :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a template. This is in C++, by the way.

```
template<typename T> class object {
private:
    static int count;
public:
    object() { count++; }
    object(const object&) { count++; }
    ~object() { count--; }
    static int GetCount() { return count; }
};
template<typename T> int object<T>::count = 0;
```

RTTI solution:

```
class object {
    static std::map<std::string, int> counts;
public:
    object() { counts[typeid(*this).name()]++; }
    object(const object&) { counts[typeid(*this).name()]++; }
    ~object() { counts[typeid(*this).name()]--; }
    template<typename T> int GetObjectsOfType() {
        return counts[typeid(T).name()];
    }
    int GetObjectsOfType(std::string type) {
        return counts[type];
    }
};
std::map<std::string, int> object::counts;
```

RTTI is less invasive and allows run-time selection of the type to be queried, but the template has far less overhead and you can use it to count every derived class individually, whereas RTTI can only count the most derived classes individually.

Comment: Cue the usual argument whether `typeinfo::name()` is guaranteed to return distinct strings for all types. Obviously it does in practice, but to play safe `counts` could be a map from `typeinfo*` to `int`, with a custom comparator `return *lhs < *rhs;`

Comment: @Steve: Pretty sure that it's entirely implementation defined, but I'm also pretty sure that all implementations do give unique strings.

Comment: yeah, love that C++ 's implementation defined, and (often necessary) all implementations defined assumptions afterwards

Comment: I checked, and it seems that in MSVC10, type_info provides a hash_code() function for this kind of purpose. But I can't speak as to whether or not that's Standard and I'm pretty sure that it's not C++03.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can implement the counting function to the common super class of your hirachy.

This base class contains a Map - associating the classes to the number of instances.
If a instance of base or one of its sub class is created, then the constructor ins invoked.
The constructor increase the number of instances of the concreate class.

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Base {

    /** Threadsave counter */
    private static final ConcurrentMap<Class<? extends Base>, AtomicInteger>
       instancesByClass 
       = new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<? extends Base>, AtomicInteger>(
            10);

    /** The only one constructor of base */
    public Base() {
        Class<? extends Base> concreateClass = this.getClass();
        AtomicInteger oldValue = instancesByClass.putIfAbsent(concreateClass,
                new AtomicInteger(1));
        if (oldValue != null) {
            oldValue.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    /* DEMO starts here */
    public static class SubA extends Base{
    }

    public static class SubB extends Base{
    }

    public static class SubSubA extends SubA{
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printNumbers();
        new SubA();
        new SubA();

        new SubB();

        new SubSubA();

        printNumbers();
    }

    private static void printNumbers() {
        // not thread save!
        for (Entry<Class<? extends Base>, AtomicInteger> item : instancesByClass
                .entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(item.getKey().getName() + "  :  "
                    + item.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as mentioned in question, there is (run-time type)-based solution for Java/C#, but much slower -> question is not about that, I can write this kind of code in Java, C#

Comment: @peenut: You think this.getClass(); is to slow? (i missed this part of your question)

Comment: nice way, dynamic class change is another way; however, you have to use map, that is slower, but incrementing/decrementing might be faster (I didn't test) than Map<Class, AtomaticInteger> approach? Did u test that?

Comment: I did no performance test, but I tested the code. -- I used the AtomaticInteger and ConcurrentMap mainly because of treading issues, because I do not want to restrict the useage and do not want to use syncronized blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net, generics could be used to accomplish this. The following technique will not work in Java due to [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure).

```
public static class InstanceCounter<T>
{
    private static int _counter;

    public static int Count { get { return _counter; }}

    public static void Increase()
    {
        _counter++;
    }

    public static void Decrease()
    {
        _counter--;
    }
}
```

Now in your classes, be it base or subclasses, use it as follows:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        InstanceCounter<SomeClass>.Increase();        
    }

    ~SomeClass()
    {
        InstanceCounter<SomeClass>.Decrease();
    }
}
```

You don't have to include the instance count property in every class either, it is only needed on the `InstanceCounter` class.

```
int someClassCount = InstanceCounter<SomeClass>.Count;
```

**Note**: this sample does not require classes to inherit the instance counter class.

If one can afford to burn the one-superclass restriction in .Net, the following would also work:

```
public class InstanceCounter<T>
{
    private static int _counter;

    public static int Count { get { return _counter; }}

    protected InstanceCounter<T>()
    {
        _counter++;
    }

    ~InstanceCounter<T>()
    {
        _counter--;
    }
}

public class SomeClass : InstanceCounter<SomeClass>
{
}
```

Then retrieving the count:

```
int someClassCount = InstanceCounter<SomeClass>.Count;
```

or

```
int someClassCount = SomeClass.Count;
```

**Note2**: As mentioned in the comments, using the finalizer (`~SomeClass`) is slow, and will only decrease the counter when the instance is actually collected by the GC. To get around this one would have to introduce deterministic "freeing" of instances, e.g. implementing `IDisposable`.

Comment: This sample means adding code to derived class, which looks much worse than CRTP solution for c++

Comment: With some caveats around using a destructor: Expensive and Late.

Comment: that caveats are (or should be) known to Java/C# developer, let's not get sidetracked ;-)

Comment: @peenut - I agree it looks worse. I chose to show this variant first since at least in .Net, one doesn't always have the luxury of subclassing.

Comment: in C# you have no multiple inheritance hierarchy, so this way works only for very simple cases: imagine classes object->A->B, object wants to add some static functionality, as well as A, you define class object<T>, class A<T>, and class B : object<B>, A<B> is impossible

Comment: or if you have not just InstanceCounter<T>, but also SomeOtherFunctionality<T>, you cannot inherit both of them: SomeClass : InstanceCounter<SomeClass>, SomeOtherFunctionality<SomeClass>

Comment: @peenut - that is exactly why I showed a way to do it without inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that if you if you actually want the injected/whatever class to actually do something useful then you *must* couple it in some way to the original classes, whether it's by inheritance or direct coupling with method calls. Otherwise you've just got two wheels spinning independently.

The only alternative I can think of is to use a factory pattern that can count creations for you -- but you'd have to hack something to count decrements, like handing the object back to the factory explicitly.

Comment: classes are coupled/joined by inheritance

Comment: Apologies -- I thought you didn't want to add this sort of functionality by inheritance. Feel free to ignore :)

Answer (score 0):

Way in C# that sprung in my mind imediately:

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    static Dictionary<Type, int> _typeCounts = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public static int GetCount<T>() where T:A
    {
        if (!_typeCounts.ContainsKey(typeof(T))) return 0;

        return _typeCounts[typeof(T)];
    }

    public A()
    {
        Increment();
    }

    private void Increment()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        if (!_typeCounts.ContainsKey(type)) _typeCounts[type] = 0;
        _typeCounts[type]++;
    }

    private void Decrement()
    {
        var type = this.GetType();
        _typeCounts[type]--;            
    }

    ~A()
    {
        if (!_disposed) Decrement();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;
        Decrement();
    }
}

class B : A
{

}
```

And how to use it:

```
        A a1 = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(A.GetCount<A>());
        A a2 = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(A.GetCount<A>());            

        using(B b1 = new B())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(B.GetCount<B>());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(B.GetCount<B>());
```

The output could be done differently maybe. And its not pure OOP, but nor are C++ or Java examples in this thread. But it doesnt require a bit of code in inheriting class.

And dont forget about correcly disposing your objects!!

Comment: as I said in the question, (run-time type)-based approach is possible in c#/java, but much slower; I can write this code, I didn't ask about this

Comment: but much slower: Did you do any extensive performance profiling? Or are shooting from the side?

Comment: Come on, if you compare integer increment with map key lookup and integer increment, it is nor really that hard to compare.

Comment: Well, then you can implement same piece of code in every derived class and have perfect performance. Or you use mine code and dont have to write any code with little worse performance. But as long as you dont create hundreds of thousands of classes per second, this difference is negligible. Programing is all about compromises.

Comment: question was about better solution than map<type, int>, you didn't answer my question, just wasted time - I can write this (or similar), it's easy